# Top hits product counter in backbone

Tags: sql-server, backbone.js

I want to record the number of each product's hitting, in order to show the user which are the popular top ten items in the website, 
when user browses to product detail page like `mysite.com/productdetail/190`, 190 is item id.

`Item` table has more than 10000 records in database, is it a better way to add `Hits` column in `Item` table or create a new `SiteHits` table for storing number of hitting each item.

1. If we add Hits column to Item table :

   - Insertion will do this query : `Update Item set Hits = Hits + 1 where ID = 100`
   - Selection : `select top (10) from Item where Hits > 0 order by LastUpdate DESC`
2. Add new table :

   - Insertion : if no record match with the item id, insert a new record else update number of hits
   - Selection :  select from item and join with new table.

So the 2nd choice seem has many operation than the 1st one.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: what did I wrong, why I got down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a separate, new table for storing hits since it's just a statistic and not really a property of the item. Kind of falls in the realm of meta-data.

The benefits of keeping that data in a separate table are:

1. It's cleaner, mainly because there's no need to add an empty column to every item. If you want the items with the hits information, just do a left join from `Item` -> `Hits`. And if you just want to crunch hits data, there's no need to go through extra joins.
2. It's flexible. Maybe you want to add more information about the item - this helps prevent the existing `Item` table from becoming bloated. Or maybe you want to keep track of when the hits occur, then you also want to store time-stamp information with each hit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer linstantnoodles, please kindly read my question that I've just updated. How do you think about these choices?

Comment: It really depends. For example, are you going to care about how many hits you got for an item in a particular month? Well, that analysis isn't possible if you just store hitcount in your item table. If all you care about is ALL TIME hits, and you have no intention of adding any other forms of metadata, then yes I think storing it in your items table is fine. Otherwise, keeping it in a separate table is better - even with the extra (inexpensive) operations.

Comment: OK, I decided to create a separate table, Thanks.